# Using PowerShell to retrieve "employeeType" data from Microsoft Azure Active Directory

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I cannot retrieve all the data that I want even though I can see that the data exists while I'm viewing through the portal.

```
$users = Get-AzureADUser -All $true | `
    Where-Object {$_.CompanyName -like 'CompanyName*' | `
    Get-Random -Count 1000 | `
    Select-Object EmployeeType, GivenName, Surname, @{Name='OfficeLocation'; Expression={$_.PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName}}
```

I've changed the Company name and removed some of the objects I'm retrieving for privacy reasons. This script above is used in my Powershell window and it successfully retrieves the data I want.

I've had some struggles to get this working the way I wanted to, I even made another post here previously where I got help to retrieve the OfficeLocation. The problem back then was that it was actually named "PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName".

This time I've really tried to check all possibilities I could think of but I've yet to make it work.

So far I've tried it as the code above where I just have "EmployeeType" with nothing extra. I've also tried these two lines below since I've needed them for some other properties in the complete code.

```
@{N="EmployeeType";E={$_.ExtensionProperty.EmployeeType}}
@{N="EmployeeType";E={$_.AdditionalProperties["EmployeeType"]} }
```

[This is an example of how it looks in the AzureAD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwrxC.png)
Data is hidden for privacy reasons.

Nothing works so far.
Any and all help is appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch the employeeType of the user, you can make use of Microsoft Graph PowerShell Module.

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes User.ReadWrite.All

$users = Get-MgUser -All -Select "displayName,employeeType"

$userinfo = @()

foreach ($user in $users) {  
$userinfo += [PSCustomObject]@{  
DisplayName = $user.DisplayName  
EmployeeType = $user.employeeType  
}  
}

  
$userinfo | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

[image]

Or make use of below script:

```
$users = Get-MgUser -All -Property Id, displayname, employeetype
$users | Format-Table DisplayName, EmployeeType
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know if it is only possible to get employeeType by using Microsoft Graph Powershell Module?

I've been having a lot of issues trying to get it to work and some other commands in my code is not compatible and so on.

If it simply is not possible using the standard Windows Powershell then this is what I'll have to solve but do you possibly know why it is not possible to get this data without using Microsoft Graph? I don't see the logic behind it :)

Comment: Yeah AFAIK It is not possible via Azure AD module. You can make use of Microsoft Graph module.

Comment: Azure ad powershell module will be deprecated so make use of mg graph

Comment: I've had time to test out your solution and I can confirm that this works. I can successfully get EmployeeType by using Microsoft Graph Powershell Module. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at my tenant I don't have that property on the user object but I don't have on-prem sync enabled.

This answer suggests that you need to use the graph module to retrieve the data however you need to ensure those properties are synced from on-prem.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1004754/set-employee-type-from-powershell

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes User.ReadWrite.All  
Select-MgProfile -Name beta  
Get-MgUser -UserId harpreet@contoso.com | Select -Property EmployeeType  
Update-MgUser -UserId harpreet@contoso.com -EmployeeType FTE
```